# Not displaying a form in a new tab

Tags: html

I have a page `principal.php` and the `main.php`. When I click the principal section it opens the principal form in a new tab. I don't want it. I would like to display the form in the principal section. How can I do this?

main.php

```
<html>
<head>
       <title>e-Statistics</title>
<style>
  .body{
      margin: 0;

  }

  .nav{
      width: 115%;
      height:40px;
      background:black;
     text-align:center;
  }
   .nav ul{
     width: 800px;
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:0;
  }
   .nav ul li{
     list-style: none;

   }
   .nav ul li a{
      float: left;
      text-decoration:none;
      display:block;
      padding:10px 40px;
      color:#ff9933 ;
      border-right:1px solid #ccc;
   }
   .nav ul li a:hover{
      color:white;

   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="nav">
    <ul>

        <li><a href="principal.php">Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href="acad_director.php">Academic Director</a></li>
        <li><a href="lecturer.php">Lecturer</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

 principal.php

    <?php

       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       switch ($_POST['program']) {
       case 'Computer Science':
       include 'csreadprog.php';
       break;
       }   
       exit;
      }   
    ?>

     <html>
     <body>
        <form method="POST">
        <b>Programs:<b/>
        <select name="program"> 
        <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
        <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option> 
        <option value="BAED">BAED</option>
        <option value="Psychology">Psychology</option>
        <option value="English Studies">English Studies</option></select><br/><br/>

        <b>Year:<b/>
        <select name="year"> 
        <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option> 
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option></select><br/><br/>

        <b>Services:<b/>
        <select name="services"> 
        <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
        <option value="Library">Library</option> 
        <option value="IT Facilities">IT Facilities</option>
        <option value="IT Services">IT Services</option>
        <option value="Services and Support">Services and Support</option>
        <option value="Clubs and Societies">Clubs and Societies</option>
        <option value="Other facilities ">Other facilities</option></select> <br/><br/>

    <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you want to show the navigation bar on each page.

The solution to that is to add the style code in the head tags and the list which is your navigation bar in the body as you have it in the main.php

Your code can be like this one below ...

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    switch ($_POST['program']){

    case 'BSc Computer Science':
        include 'csreadprog.php';
        break;
    case 'BSc Psychology':
        include 'psyreadprog.php';
        break;
    case 'BA Business Administration':
        include 'baedreadprog.php';
        break;
    }

    switch ($_POST['services']){

    case 'Library':
        include 'libraryread.php';
        break;

    case 'IT Services and Facilities':
        include'itserviceread.php';
        break;

    case 'Front Desk':
        include'frontdeskread.php';
        break;

    case 'Course Administrator':
        include'courseadminread.php';
        break;

    case 'International Student Office':
        include'stofficeread.php';
        break;

    case 'Clubs and Societies':
        include'clubsread.php';
        break;
    }

    switch($_POST['program'] && $_POST['criteria']){

    case 'BSc Computer Science' && 'I have found the unit interesting':
      include 'readcsprogcrit.php';
      break;

    case 'BSc Psychology' && 'I have gained knowledge':
      include 'readpsyprogcrit.php';
      break;

    case 'BA Business Administration' && 'I have acquired skills':
      include 'readbaedprogcrit.php';
      break;

    }

    exit;
}   
?>

<html>
<head>

<style>
    .body{
        margin: 0;

    }

    .nav{
        width: 115%;
        height:40px;
        background:black;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .nav ul{
        width: 800px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav ul li{
        list-style: none;

    }
    .nav ul li a{
        float: left;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        padding:10px 40px;
        color:#ff9933 ;
        border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .nav ul li a:hover{
        color:white;

    }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="nav">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="principal.php">Principal</a></li>
            <li><a href="acad_director.php">Academic Director</a></li>
            <li><a href="lecturer.php">Lecturer</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>

    <form method="POST" action="principal.php">
    <b>Programs:<b/>
    <select name="program"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option value="Computer Science"> BSc Computer Science</option> 
    <option value="BAED">BA Business Administration</option>
    <option value="Psychology">BSc Psychology</option></select><br/><br/>

    <b>Departments:<b/>
    <select name="department"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option> 
    <option value="BAED">BAED</option>
    <option value="Psychology">Psychology</option></select><br/><br/>

    <b>Year:<b/>
    <select name="year"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option> 
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option></select><br/><br/>

    <b>Criteria:<b/>
    <select name="criteria"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option value="I have found the unit interesting">I have found the unit interesting</option> 
    <option value="I have gained knowledge">I have gained knowledge</option>
    <option value="I have acquired skills">I have acquired skills</option>
    <option value="Useful other resources">Useful other resources</option></select><br/><br/>

    <b>Services:<b/>
    <select name="services"> 
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <option value="Library">Library</option> 
    <option value="Course Administrator">Course Administrator</option>
    <option value="International Student Office">International Student Office</option>
    <option value="IT Services and Facilities">IT Services and Facilities</option>
    <option value="Front Desk">Front Desk</option>
    <option value="Clubs and Societies">Clubs and Societies</option></select><br/><br/>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_self">Open it on same page</a>
```

use this code to target your hyperlinks on the same page. Hope this helped.

Comment: where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a browser issue...

But just incase...

```
<a href="principal.php" target="_self">Principal</a>
```

Just add the `target="_self"`.